# Unknown scheduled job creating duplicate contacts

Tags: scheduled-job

So I have a mystery. Every day at 17:40+-2 minutes, the system creates a number of duplicate contacts.

[image]
These contacts largely have the same set of names:

[image]
Other things of note:
1. All of these contacts show as being created by themselves.
2. There are no scheduled jobs for that time that I can tell

Anybody got an idea?

Comment: "All of these contacts show as being created by themselves" - that could indicate that they are created via an online form (such as a profile, contribution page, event page, a webform etc.) or when users are created in your CMS.

Comment: do these contacts have a cms user record associated with it, if so that may provide a clue

Comment: @fabian - They could be, but I don't see any sign of them being created through Caldera/Wordpress (I am using Caldera for all but our membership forms).

Comment: @petednz-fuzion - Forgot to mention we are on Wordpress and have sync enabled. All three have two emails, but then so do dozens of other contacts